# Problems when I use C language "sscanf" to parse a string

Tags: c++

When I wanted to parse a string "`INSERT 3 zhaoliu 13`", I used sscanf, but the debugging interface on the left of vscode told me that the first digit of "name" was '00', that is, only "haoliu" was scanned, I'm guessing it's a buffer issue, but how do I fix it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9SI6.png)
Below is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include"string.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char INSERT[10];
    int id;
    char name[15];
    short strength;
    string instr = "INSERT 3 zhaoliu 13";
    sscanf(instr.c_str(), "%s %d %s %d", INSERT, &id, name, &strength);


}
```

I tried to check a lot of information, but couldn't find a solution

Comment: Your debugger is pointing at the line `string instr = "INSERT 3 zhaoliu 13";`, which probably means that you are looking at the values of the variables at that point in your program. However, at that point, the `sscanf` line has not been executed yet, so it should not matter what content the array `name` has. You should execute the line with the `sscanf` command and only then look at the content of `name`.

Comment: 1) For std::string you want `#include <string>` 2) Is there a reason you are mixing C and C++ style strings like this? 3) %d is not the correct format specifier to go with &strength. It should be %hd. [There is a chart here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: If `sscanf` does not return 4, then it did not read all these fields. You should check the return value before you assume any of your (uninitialized) variables actually received a value.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel，Thanks，I know what you mean，and In fact, I have indeed executed "sscanf", and then the pointer of vscode points to the above "string instr = "INSERT 3 zhaoliu 13", this may be a problem with the compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've specified the wrong type for one of your variables. `strength` is a short so it should correspond to `%hd`, not to `%d`.

```
sscanf(instr.c_str(), "%s %d %s %hd", INSERT, &id, name, &strength);
```

In the future, I recommend compiling with warnings turned on. With `-Wall` on g++, I get a warning indicating exactly this.

```
so_scanf2.cpp:12:51: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int*’, but argument 6 has type ‘short int*’ [-Wformat=]
   12 |     int result = sscanf(instr.c_str(), "%s %d %s %d", INSERT, &id, name, &strength);
      |                                                  ~^                      ~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                   |                      |
      |                                                   int*                   short int*
      |                                                  %hd
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the format, it was indeed the problem, maybe my foundation was wrong, after using "%hd" it did solve the problem，Thanks